# Laravel timezone not working on AWS ubuntu

Tags: php, timezone, laravel-5

I want to change the timezone of my project to IST. So that all the datetime operations for Eg: created_at,deleted_at, timestamp fields in DB are saved in IST format. Which laravel 5 allows easily by changing project_root/config/app.php file. We just have to change **'timezone' => 'UTC'** to **'timezone' => 'IST'**.

Now if I do make this change in my local, application works perfectly with IST timezone. But when I am trying to set the same on AWS EC2 instance it stores the datetime in DB in UTC format only.

What could be the problem?

Is it even the right way what I am doing?

Comment: Try changing it in the php.ini and restarting the service.